# Google Map's language via Angular JS variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm still learning Angular and Google Map API, and I'm having a sort of road block. I'm trying to fetch the map language using angular variable, like this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language={{language}}&sensor=false"></script>
```

When the page finish loading, I can see that the &language=xx is printed fine on the script source, though the map is still in English :(

I think google map loads, just before the language parameter get's printed. Is there any other way to solve this?

---

Additional: All of my script files are located at the bottom of my page

```
<body>
    .
    ..
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language={{language}}&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="localize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="route-planner-widget.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have thought that maybe, I should call the google map script after my angular script (route-planner-widget.js) finish loading first, but it seems, it's not working either.

Comment: Is it possible that you've included the Google Maps script elsewhere on the page?

Comment: Do you get what you expect if you hardcode for example `...&language=fr...` instead?

Comment: yes i do get it.. &language=tl.. but like i said, the map is still in english :(

Comment: oh sorry Anto, my first comment is not correct. Yes, when hardcoded, like &language=tl, i get what I expect.